# Check file modification date and copy it to target direction and copy only those that are modified in given date

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

So, I have this code

```
target_dir = "/mnt/..."

for source_dir in glob.iglob("/mnt/.../*bla.png"):
      file_date=(os.path.getmtime(source_dir))
      d=datetime.datetime(2022,2,3)
      if file_date>= d and file_date < (d+datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
        shutil.copy(source_dir, target_dir)
```

but when I'm trying to run it, It gives me this error

```
File "a.py", line 33, in <module>
if file_date > d and file_date < (d+datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

I'm stuck and i don't know what to do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.getmtime()` returns a float, while `datetime.datetime()` returns a `datetime` instance and that's why you are getting the error. One solution is to convert the float to datetime using the `fromtimestamp` method:

```py
file_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(source_dir))
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining and helping. :)